# JUnit test passes whether I throw exception or not

Tags: unit-testing, testing, exception, junit

I am just starting to learn JUnit.  I tried looking elsewhere for this answer but I couldn't find it.  Suppose I write a JUnit test method that expects an exception, something like this:  (math being an instance of the class I wrote)

```
 @Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
    public void testAdd_String() {
        System.out.println("testing add number to string");
        double result = math.add("lakd", "2");
    }
```

Now for the method I would like to test:

```
public double add(String operand1, String operand2) {
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(operand1);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(operand2);
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

My test passes both when I have `throws NumberFormatException` on the method header and when it is not there.  Is this the expected behavior or JUnit?  Is there a way through a JUnit test to ensure that the throws clause is present in my method?

Comment: I am using JUnit4 in netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `throws` to a method declaration is just a warning label, saying "Look, I can throw this exception at any time! You'd better be prepared for it." You only actually throw a exception when you use the `throw` statement, or a method you call uses a `throw` statement.

[`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is a *runtime exception* or *unchecked exception* (subclass of `RuntimeException`) and thus it never needs to be declared on a method using `throws`. You can still catch it in a try/catch block, but unlike *checked* exceptions (like `FileNotFoundException`, which is a subclass of `Exception`) you do not need to declare it on the method in order to throw it.

You should not need to test that a method has a checked exception that it can throw--only whether or not it actually throws the exception. In fact, as you have it already, the `expected` parameter of `@Test` means that the test will fail if your method stops *throwing* a `NumberFormatException`, such as if you changed the line to:

```
double result = math.add("1", "2");
```

If you feel that an exception is "expected" enough that someone using your method MUST have a try/catch block surrounding it, you should create your own subclass of `Exception`--but be forewarned that this will likely make your method more difficult to use cleanly.